# Sequence Number is not allowed in Explicit Cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can't use a sequence in a Explicit Cursors.

Error: PL/SQL:ORA-02287: Sequence number not allowed here

Code:

```
CURSOR c_service_consumer IS
  select  ops$KLI.SVC_SEQ.Nextval,
          adr_cli_id_s,         
          null,
          svc_srv_id_s
```

....

I tried to use like this:

```
CURSOR c_service_consumer IS
  select  SELECT ops$KLI.SVC_SEQ.Nextval FROM DUAL,
          adr_cli_id_s,         
          null,
          svc_srv_id_s
```

And is the same error.

This is the Cursor:

```
TYPE l_service_consumer_row IS TABLE OF TA_MAIN.SERVICE_CONSUMER%ROWTYPE;
l_service_consumer     l_service_consumer_row;

CURSOR c_service_consumer IS
  select  ops$KLI.SVC_SEQ.Nextval,
          a.adr_cli_id_s,         
          svc_prp_id_s,
          svc_srv_id_s
  from ops$luan.be_1304_grain_adr a
  left outer join ta_main.clients c on (a.adr_cli_id_s = c.cli_id_s);

BEGIN

OPEN c_service_consumer;
FETCH c_service_consumer BULK COLLECT INTO l_service_consumer;
CLOSE c_service_consumer;

/*Insert the collection of values*/
FORALL i IN INDICES OF l_service_consumer SAVE EXCEPTIONS
       INSERT INTO TA_MAIN.SERVICE_CONSUMER
       VALUES l_service_consumer(i);
```

Comment: Nextval pseudocolumn is allowed in cursor, unless you use an "ORDER BY" clause. Please post the whole query...

Comment: Hi guys: I need to create a cursor with the sequence because I need to load a collection (NESTED TABLE) with the result of the cursor (BUL COLLECT INTO), and after that, insert into the collection into a Table with the sentence FORALL. That's why, it's neccesary to have all values in the cursor before to load in the collection and then insert into the table.

Comment: You could bulk collect the cursor column NULL, then populate the it within a LOOP, and then write it back with a FORALL.

Comment: What you're doing works for me - [slightly simplified SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91259/1). Which line is the error reported against - are you sure it's coming form the cursor declaration? Or have you still simplified the cursor at all? I can only make this happen with an `order by`, or if I `union` the query, though there are probably other similar things that implictily do some ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps (not tested)

```
TYPE l_service_consumer_row  IS TABLE OF TA_MAIN.SERVICE_CONSUMER%ROWTYPE 
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_service_consumer     l_service_consumer_row;
fetch_size   NUMBER := 5000; -- scale the value

CURSOR c_service_consumer IS
  select  -1 id,
          a.adr_cli_id_s,         
          svc_prp_id_s,
          svc_srv_id_s
  from ops$luan.be_1304_grain_adr a
  left outer join ta_main.clients c on (a.adr_cli_id_s = c.cli_id_s);

BEGIN

OPEN c_service_consumer;
loop
   FETCH c_service_consumer BULK COLLECT INTO l_service_consumer LIMIT fetch_size;        
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_service_consumer.COUNT  LOOP
     l_service_consumer(i).id = ops$KLI.SVC_SEQ.Nextval;    
   END LOOP;    

  /*Insert the collection of values*/
   FORALL i IN INDICES OF l_service_consumer SAVE EXCEPTIONS
       INSERT INTO TA_MAIN.SERVICE_CONSUMER
       VALUES l_service_consumer(i);  

   EXIT WHEN c_service_consumer%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_service_consumer;
End;
```